# Magento Full Page Cache (FPC) does not get warmed

Tags: full-page-cache

I experience a weird issue on Magento ver. 1.14.2.0. The FPC was enabled in backend (Cache Management) but var/full_page_cache didn't exist. I figured out that app/etc/enterprise.xml was missing. After I restored it from a vanilla Magento installation the folder got created. But the size of the folder does not increase although I'm hitting several category and product pages:

```
du -sh full_page_cache/
4.0K    full_page_cache/
```

It stays empty. I've already set the folder to 777 but no change.

Does anyone know what is may causing the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: If `app/etc/enterprise.xml` was missing, probably other cache related files are missing as well.  Check that the `Enterprise_PageCache` module exists for a start...

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! Only the enterprise.xml was missing, caused by .gitignore. It turned out that FPC wasn't configured correctly in etc/local.xml

Comment: Great, glad it's working for you now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check:

1. If app/etc/enterprise.xml exists and check its content
2. If app/etc/local.xml contains a `<full_page_cache>` node. Maybe its not configured correctly or configured to use Redis or another cache.